# Integrating 1 hibernate search in two Spring boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to use the  hibernate search indexes into two application like resource and authentication server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what the documentation of hibernate search it can through merging the indexes thank you. my bad.

if someone is looking for a clue also please refer to this link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-sharing-indexes

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether you can us the same index from multiple instances of a single application, yes it's possible.

The easiest way to do that would be to use the (experimental) Elasticsearch integration of Search 5, which would store the indexes in a remote Elasticsearch cluster instead of locally on the filesystem.
If you're interested in this, I would suggest having a look at [Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started), currently in development, which already provides better support for the Elasticsearch integration than Search 5 did.

If you want to stick with the Lucene integration without an Elasticsearch server, it's possible, but quite complex. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture for more information.

Comment: its not an instance of a single application but two different application. but thanks to the answer i appreciate it .